# How to boot from pendrive?

Tags: ubuntu, bios

I got ubuntu distro iso in pendrive. From bios boot menu whatever I choose it starts Windows, not booting pendrive. How to boot from pendrive?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB-HDD should be the appropriate device, and you want it above hard disk in priority.

Comment: yes, I had to change disk priority in advanced bios settings

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply boot from an iso image in a removable storage media.

You will have to make the flash / pen drive bootable and then connect it to the machine to boot from it. From the screen shot, I assume you're seeing the pen drive listed in BIOS and it is selected as primary boot device. (Currently it's your hard disk)

In-order to create a bootable drive, you can use programs like [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/)  or [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)

Ubuntu has a well detailed tutorial if you require their assistance : [Create a bootable USB drive](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Be aware:

- Creating a bootable drive will erase existing data from the flash / pen drive, while you choose formatting.

  - Always select a blank usb drive which has atleast 4Gb capacity.
- Make sure you have made a note of drive letter assigned for the target USB drive in MS Windows (In My PC).

Comment: You absolutely can simply write an UBUNTU ISO directly to the disk and it will boot into Ubuntu - by design. (For clarity by write I mean simething like dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdX where SDX is the pen drive)

Comment: Of course you can. Here the user sounded novice and a MS Windows user, which is why the answer is specific to it. The 'dd' command is easy to do the task as well as end up with data loss if wrong disk is selected. More about using terminal in Linux to create a bootable drive : https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal

Comment: that wasn't my problem but good post anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) for creating a multiboot pendrive for Linux Distro, Windows &  other OS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Explaining HOW to do this will make this an answer. Please edit your post to turn it into a full answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1220246)